# log4j temporary fix in elasticsearch helm chart using Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, log4j, kubernetes-helm, elk

I was trying to setup an elasticsearch cluster in AKS using helm chart but due to the log4j vulnerability, I wanted to set it up with option `-Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups` set to `true`. I am getting unknown flag error when I pass the arguments in helm commands.
Ref: https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/elastic/elasticsearch/6.8.16

```
helm upgrade  elasticsearch elasticsearch --set imageTag=6.8.16 esJavaOpts "-Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true"
Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'D' in -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true
```

I have also tried to add below in `values.yaml` file

```
esConfig: {}
#  elasticsearch.yml: |
#    key:
#      nestedkey: value
log4j2.properties: |
  -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups = true
```

but the values are not adding to the `/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/jvm.options`, `/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/log4j2.properties` or in the environment variables.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, here's a good source of knowledge about mitigating [Log4j2 security issue](https://xeraa.net/blog/2021_mitigate-log4j2-log4shell-elasticsearch/) if this is the reason you reached here.

Here's how you can write your `values.yaml` for the Elasticsearch chart:

```
esConfig:
  log4j2.properties: |
    logger.discovery.name = org.elasticsearch.discovery
    logger.discovery.level = debug
```

A ConfigMap will be generated by Helm:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-master-config
  ...
data:
  log4j2.properties: |
    logger.discovery.name = org.elasticsearch.discovery
    logger.discovery.level = debug
```

And the Log4j configuration will be mount to your Elasticsearch as:

```
...
volumeMounts:
  ...
  - name: esconfig
    mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/log4j2.properties
    subPath: log4j2.properties
```

**Update:** How to set and add multiple configuration files.

You can setup other ES configuration files in your `values.yaml`, all the files that you specified here will be part of the ConfigMap, each of the files will be mounted at `/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/` in the Elasticsearch container. Example:

```
esConfig:
  elasticsearch.yml: |
    node.master: true
    node.data: true

  log4j2.properties: |
    logger.discovery.name = org.elasticsearch.discovery
    logger.discovery.level = debug

  jvm.options: |
    # You can also place a comment here.
    -Xmx1g -Xms1g -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true

  roles.yml: |
    click_admins:
      run_as: [ 'clicks_watcher_1' ]
      cluster: [ 'monitor' ]
      indices:
      - names: [ 'events-*' ]
        privileges: [ 'read' ]
        field_security:
          grant: ['category', '@timestamp', 'message' ]
        query: '{"match": {"category": "click"}}'
```

**ALL of the configurations above are for illustration only to demonstrate how to add multiple configuration files in the values.yaml. Please substitute these configurations with your own settings.**

Comment: Thanks, May I ask one more? Currently the configuration files are: `[elasticsearch@elasticsearch-master-0 ~]$ ls /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/ elasticsearch.keystore elasticsearch.yml jvm.options log4j2.properties role_mapping.yml roles.yml users users_roles`
Though I added the configuration parameter in log4j2.properties file, I really wanted to add the configuration in jvm.options but could not find how to do this. Can you help me as i am not sure about the precedence of the configurations?

Comment: Sure, checkout the updated answer about how to add other configurable files.

Comment: This answer is incorrect in 2 ways. The log4j2 flag should be set in jvm settings and it is not reccommended to overwrite the jvm.options file like this. ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/advanced-configuration.html#set-jvm-options

Answer (score 0):

if you update and put a value under esConfig, you will need to remove the curly brackets

```
esConfig:
log4j2.properties: |
key = value
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest to change the /config/jvm.options file and at the end add

-Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true

Comment: It is not reccommended to modify the jvm.options file like this. ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/advanced-configuration.html#set-jvm-options

Answer (score 0):

The helm chart [has an option](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/blob/main/elasticsearch/values.yaml#L82) to set java options.

```
esJavaOpts: "" # example: "-Xmx1g -Xms1g"
```

In your case, setting it like this should be the solution:

```
esJavaOpts: "-Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true"
```

Comment: `The ES_JAVA_OPTS variable overrides all other JVM options. We do not recommend using ES_JAVA_OPTS in production.` - [Go to the last lines here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/advanced-configuration.html)

Answer (score -1):

As I see in updated in elastic repository [values.yml](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/blob/main/elasticsearch/values.yaml):

> esConfig: {} 
> log4j2.properties: | 
> key = value

Probably need to uncomment log4j2.properties part.